# Aggregation with Elasticsearch and Java

Tags: elasticsearch, java

I am new to ES and now I have basic queries and bulk inserts working. I want to add an aggregation to count word pair occurrences in the entire database to work out word densities later.

The data has the form -

```
PartNumber, ShopName, WordPair, WordPairCount.
```

I am unsure how to write the aggregation in Java. I want the final results to be as follows:

Before (default)

```
A3003, Smiths Shop, 30cm plate, 1
A3001, Johns Shop, 30cm plate, 1
A3005, Johns Shop, 15cm plate, 1
```

After Aggregation

```
A3003, Smiths Shop, 30cm plate, 2
A3001, Johns Shop, 30cm plate, 2
A3005, Johns Shop, 15cm plate, 1
```

The data is loaded with the counts set to one, and then I want to run an aggregation to effectively sum the default counts over the PartNumber, ShopName as key. Hence the final data will show that the **15cm plate** is not widely sold but the **30cm plate** is widely sold (in both stores).

In SQL this would be a simple group by with an update on a join. But SQL is too slow as I found out.

I did not test the sql equivalent but I think it would be -

```
update p
    set p.wordpartcount = w.x
from part p
inner join (
    select wordpair, count(*) as x
from part
group by wordpair
) as w on w.wordpair = p.wordpair
```

Comment: The above result will come if you do groupByWordPair as there are 2 count for 30 cm and 1 for 15cm. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: I added the sql to clarify my request.

Comment: You want to aggregate on WordPair in java??

Comment: Yes with ES (and Java).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = elasticsearchTemplate.client.prepareSearch(name_of_index)
            .setIndices(name_of_index)
            .setTypes(name_of_type)
            .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("groupByWordPair")
            .field("wordPair").size(0))

    SearchResponse searchResponse = searchRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet()
    StringTerms stringTerms = searchResponse?.aggregations?.asMap?.get("groupByWordPair")
    List<StringTerms.Bucket> bucketList = stringTerms?.buckets
```

`bucketList` found above will contain list of `Buckets`. Each `bucket` will have `key` as wordPair and `docCount` as its count.

Hope this helps.